# Select all rows present in Table A OR Table B

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get the resulting row if the foreign id present in Table A or in Table B.

I have 3 tables: `events`, `pdf_results` and `live_Results`. I would like to select all events with `pdf_results` OR `live_Results`.

I have tried following query but it's not working when results are available in both tables.

```
SELECT
  events.*,
  live_results.id,
  pdf_results.id
FROM events
LEFT JOIN pdf_results
  ON pdf_results.eventId = events.id
LEFT JOIN live_Results
  ON live_Results.eventId = events.id;
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b3de7/2)

Comment: Can we get a sample of your database structure + content ?

Comment: @giollianosulit I have added demo fiddle in the question.

Comment: Hi. "get the resulting row if the foreign id present in Table A or in Table B" is not clear. "select all events with pdf_results OR live_Results" is also not clear, but is maybe closer to making sense. Also "it's not working" and "when results are available in both tables" are not clear. Please use enough words & phrases & sentences to say what you mean. Also please read & act on [mcve]. That includes DDL, DML, input, output & desired output. (And when you have an sqlfiddle link please also have relevant code in your question.)

Comment: `union` returns rows that are in a left table *or* are in a right table. `join` returns rows whose subrows are in a left table *and* in a left table. So a (`join` with) `on` or `where` can only return rows with this `or` that *and* the appropriate subrows are in each table. `left join` returns rows returns rows that are in an `inner join` *or* that don't and have a subrow in a left table and have `null` for each column of a  right table. So again some queries of a special form with "or" and/or "and" can be phrased with it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097

Answer (score 0):

How about just using `exists`?

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM events e
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pdf_results pr WHERE pr.eventId = e.id) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM live_Results lr WHERE lr.eventId = e.id);
```

Comment: Would this still display duplicate results if event has pdf+live result?

Comment: @giollianosulit . . . Of course not.  Conditions in the `where` clause do not duplicate results.

Comment: @giollianosulit Yes. It should give 2 rows if result is available in pdf and in live. Thank you for mentioning.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Yep thought so, was just asking as it looks like he wanted 2 results

Comment: @MikeRoss . . . I'm confused.  Do you want two rows or not?  You question is complaining about duplicates, so it certainly seems that you do not want multiple rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I did not think of that scenario until Giolliano pointed it out. I have updated my question.

Comment: @MikeRoss Where does it say that in the updated question?

Answer (score 0):

You can join with a `UNION` query:

```
SELECT e.*, r.result_type
FROM events AS e
JOIN (SELECT eventId, 'pdf' AS result_type FROM pdf_results
      UNION ALL
      SELECT eventId, 'live' AS result_type FROM live_results) AS r
ON e.id = r.eventId
```

Adding the `result_type` column allows us to know which results table it matched, and we'll get two rows if it matches both.

You could also use your original query, and add:

```
WHERE pdf_results.eventId IS NOT NULL OR live_results.eventId IS NOT NULL
```

You won't get two rows when it matches twice, but you'll be able to tell from the two `eventId` columns which results table it was found in.